# any way to send a function with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

guys.

I want to send a function to browser with socket.io, but failed to do it.

On server side, I response a function with `emit`, but I get a undefined on browser.

Is there any way to get a function from server with socketio?

there is my code.

```
// server.js
var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var file = new(static.Server)();
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8000);

io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('schedule', function() {
        console.log('SCHEDULE TASK');
        socket.emit('schedule', function() { console.log('hello world'); });
    });
});

// client.js

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
socket.on('schedule', function(fn) {
    fn();
});
socket.emit('schedule');
```

Comment: There is most likely a better way to do whatever you're going for, honestly. But you *could*, if you really had to, send `(function() { ... }).toString()` to the client and `eval` the result. You really, really shouldn't, though.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot send an actual function.  You could send a string of Javascript and then you could turn that into a function in the client.

But, I'd suggest you really ought to rethink what you're trying to do here.  Generally, the client already has the code it needs (from the script tags that it downloaded) and you send the client data which it then passes to the code it already has or data that it uses to make decisions about which code that it already has to call.

If you show us the real world problem you're trying to solve, we can likely suggest a much better solution than sending a string of Javascript code to the client.

If you really wanted to send a function, you would have to turn it into a string first, send the string, then use the string to turn it back into a function in the client by using a `Function` object or `eval()` or creating your own dynamic script tag with inline source.

Comment: it is a real world problem with me. I had try to send a string to client, but with some closure variable it don't work well. anyway, thanks.

Comment: @peerxu - No.  You're describing your attempted solution to a problem.  You have not yet actually described the problem you are really trying to solve.  That is called the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here at StackOverflow and makes it less likely you'll find the best solution to your actual problem.  You've decided that sending a function to the client is the best way to solve your problem so you're asking for help with that, but we're betting that there are much better ways to solve your problem if you explain what the actual problem is.

Comment: @peerxu - and yes, you cannot send a closure to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can only send strings via `socket.io`, not functions. That being said, I suggest you to send function names instead.

```
//server.js
socket.emit('schedule', 'helloworld');

//client.js
function helloworld(){
    console.log('hello world');
}
socket.on('schedule',function(name){
    window[name](); //hello world
});
```

Comment: yep, it it a way to solve the problem. but I want to load the function dynamic. thanks for your answer.